# Point Domain to Page (Permanent)

Tags: seo, domains, dns

I have a sub-page on my site that can be access at `example.com/bar`. This page represents a special service on my website that has gathered a lot of attention on the internet.

I don't want people to have to remember the address of this page on my site, so I registered `foo.example` which is easier to remember. I disabled `example.com/bar` from being shown in search results using a meta tag so that it doesn't take attention away from `foo.example`, but now I need `foo.example` to load the content of `example.com/bar` and show up in search results as if it was.

What DNS setting should I use to make this kind of alias, and how can I optimize my dedicated domain for search results?

Comment: DNS cannot do what you want.  DNS can only point a domain to a server.  Rather than ask "What DNS setting", you should be asking how to configure your server.

Comment: There is no way that the domain is going to simply replace the page in search results.     Search engines are very likely to judge content on a different domain to be not the same as a page on a larger site.    I don't know if you could get better rankings in the end, but your rankings are almost certainly to suffer for the first year or two when moving a page to its own domain.

Comment: I've closed this because you have asked two very distinct questions in one post.   "How do I set this up" and "How do I do SEO" should be asked as separate questions.   Please edit this question to remove the SEO portion, so that this can be re-opened.

Answer (score 2):

Two important things:

- `robots.txt` directives [do not keep a page out of search results](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062608?hl=en&ref_topic=6061961&visit_id=637232914031570213-676737903&rd=1), and it may be hurting the search equity of your page. You want as much of your search equity as possible to transfer to the new domain. Remove your `robots.txt` directive.
- You cannot use DNS to alias paths like this. DNS has no concept of anything that comes after the domain name.

To achieve the setup you want:

- Move your web app from the `example.com` server to the `foo.example` server. If you don't want to move it, you might be able to use a clever *reverse proxy* setup instead, but moving it is the more straightforward way.
- Set up your server to 301 Permanent Redirect `example.com/bar` to `foo.example`. This both redirects visitors and transfers equity. Leave it up for at least a year, preferably indefinitely.

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: sorry, I meant meta tag. corrected. The problem is that I don't want to redirect to foo.example. I want to use my new domain foo.com

Comment: `foo.com` is a real domain name owned by DigiMedia L.P.. Patrick helpfully came by and edited your question and my answer to use `foo.example` instead, because `.example` is a domain name extension that was specifically set aside to use in examples. In reality, of course, you won't want to use `foo.com` or `foo.example`, but the specific domain name that you actually own.

Comment: I wouldn't use a meta tag, either, unless you really want your page to disappear until you get it working on the new domain. You will probably want to leave your page serving and indexable right up until the point that you have the app running on your new domain and put the redirect in place at your old url.